# standalone package and user-defined macros/lengths

Tags: macros, standalone, lengths

This is my first post on this amazing website, so hi to everybody!!

I'd like to know if there is a way to pass some parametrs (macros or lengths) to a standalone file.

Here is my MWE:

Consider the following main.tex file:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{mode=buildnew}

\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{50pt}
\newcommand{\myl}{50pt}

\begin{document}    

    \ \\
    main: \the\mylen, \myl \\ 
    \includestandalone{safile}\\ 

\end{document}
```

And this is the standalone file safile.tex:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    standalone: \the\mylen, \myl\\ 

\end{document}
```

And the result that I get is the following:

```
main: 50.0pt, 50pt
standalone: 0
```

But I was expecting to see:

```
main: 50.0pt, 50pt
standalone: 50.0pt, 50pt
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: I get what you expect when i compile `main.tex`.

Comment: This is strange... I don't... I am using TeXShop on Mac. Do you think it can be some program-related preference?

Comment: Welcome! No: not a programme preference. TeXShop doesn't do the compiling. It is just an editor. There is certainly no general problem with `standalone` files picking up all kinds of definitions and settings from the main file. (Though I tend to use `\input{}` rather than `\includestandalone{}`.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Ok, with `\input{}` macros and lengths are correctly interpreted now. The reason why I was using `\includestandalone{}` is because there should be a tikz picture in the standalone file which is very heavy and I don't want it to be compiled every time. With `\includestandalone{}` is not recompiled every time (but macros and lengths are lost), with `\input{}` instead is always recompiled.

Comment: Well, I'm on TeX Live 2014, still; if I add \listfiles, I see at the end of `main.log`: `standalone.sty    2012/09/15 v1.1b Package to include TeX sub-files with preambles` among other things.

Comment: @jon I see exactly the same thing: `standalone.sty    2012/09/15 v1.1b Package to include TeX sub-files with preambles`, but still I have the same output as before with `\includestandalone{}`

Comment: I noticed just now that if I remove the `\standaloneconfig{mode=buildnew}` command everything works fine (except for the fact that the source is always recompiled)

Comment: does anybody have some news about this?

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390220/how-to-disable-grouping-for-includestandalone

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get `standalone: 0` here is because of the `\standaloneconfig{mode=buildnew}`. You are telling `standalone` to compile the subfile on its own. This calls LaTeX internally again on the subfile, then include the resulting PDF as an image. The image is kept and not built again as long the subfile does not change.

This way the macro definitions in the main file are never seen by the subfile code as they are compiled separately. The `0` is a fallback of `\the`, I guess, as `\mylen` isn't defined in this case. Actually the subfile compilation is stopped there because of that error.

However, if you compile it with the main document (e.g. by changing the `mode` or by not enabling `-shell-escape` which is needed to start the second compilation) then the subfile sees the definition.

As a solution to this I would suggest that you

1. either place the definition in an third small file `\input`ed by both other files, or
2. avoid the `buildnew` and other `build...` options for this document, but include the subfile as TeX code, not as an image.